# Google Cloud Ruby API Authorization / Client / Token handling

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm struggling a bit with the Google Cloud Ruby API in a Rails app and am looking for some guidance.  Here's a few questions and any help is appreciated.

```
      key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12('file.p12', 'notasecret')
  client = Google::APIClient.new({:application_name => "App Name", :application_version => "1.0"})
  client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
      :token_credential_uri => 'url',
      :audience => 'audience',
      :scope => 'scope',
      :issuer => '',
      :signing_key => key)
  client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
```

1. Probably most important:

   ```
   "client.authorization.fetch_access_token!"
   ```

   Does this need to be called every time?  Am I supposed to be saving off the access token and using it until it expires or does the library take care of it for me?
2. What is this for? It works as is, but I copied this value from the example I found online.  Should I be using this differently?

   ```
   'notasecret'
   ```
3. :application_name and :application_version -- What are these used for?  The doc doesn't really say.  "The name of the application using the client." I seemingly can send anything in here... http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/APIClient

Thanks for any help.  It's a bit frustrating the lack of docs on the authentication side of things for the ruby library from Google.

Comment: After more hours of searching the internet I found that version 0.8.3 of the ruby library allows for an easier way to authorize using the default credentials.

    ```client = Google::APIClient.new({:application_name => 'name',
                                                                   :application_version => 'version'})
      client.authorization = :google_app_default
      client.authorization.fetch_access_token!```

Comment: The only question I have left is if I need to save the client and/or tokens between calls or if I am supposed to run this code each time.  I've seen examples of both, but there are also different types of oauth so I'm confused as to what I need to do for the service account.  This works, but I want to make sure I'm doing what I'm supposed to be.  Should I be caching the client and/or tokens?  Thanks